# How to import file using path in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i want to import file hooks.tsx into main.tsx file.
below is the folder structure

[image]

in file header.tsx file i want to import hooks.tsx file.

i have tried to use like below

```
import something from '../../../subPage/hooks';
```

but this file cannot be resolved. not sure what path to be given here. could someone help with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to go one more level up:

```
import something from '../../../../subPage/hooks';
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer from @taghi Khavari shows you what the path is. But this might be very useful for you:

make a jsconfig.json
put the parent folder name in as baseUrl

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
  }
```

Now you can import a file as:

```
import something from 'subPage/hooks';
```

now you don't have to put all those slashes in front of it.
But you can still use  './' or '../' if you need it.

documentation:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports